Password Complexity Instructions display on Microsoft password reset portal
We are using Entra Self service password reset solutions. While user reset password it should display the Complexity requirements in the same page to guide the user.
Is it possible?
reference link: passwordreset.microsoftonline.com
or
account.activedirectory.windowsazure.com/ChangePassword.aspx
No such option or feature found on internet.

Do you want to use this feature on Azure AD B2C?

Yes anywhere, any method. if that possible to show good UI experience by showing complexity and password strength meter etc.
